# Unbounded memory growth after Rack::Timeout in a puma Rails app

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, puma

We're using Ruby 2.3.3 with a Rails 5.0 app, running on puma 3.8.2, and rack-timeout 0.4.2.

We get semi frequent Rack::Timeout exceptions that have no ill effect.  Occasionally though, something bad will happen that causes a slew of timeouts, and after that point, the puma worker process seems to just keep generating more and more live objects.  GC appears to still be running - at least, NewRelic is still reporting time spent in GC - but it doesn't seem to be having much effect:

[image: heap size graph]

The worker process keeps serving requests, but gets slower & slower as the heap size goes up, before eventually dying with out-of-memory errors.

I know this is quite a vague question, but I wondered if anyone had run into anything similar.  Any tips for diagnosing it further?

Comment: Yes, this is quite a vague question. Can you provide more details? Can you narrow this down to certain requests or path in your application? What does the application do? How big is the database? Is there more information related to the request in the log files? Do the errors in include a usefull stacktrace?

Comment: https://www.schneems.com/2017/02/21/the-oldest-bug-in-ruby-why-racktimeout-might-hose-your-server/

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I have _exactly_ the same situation. I'm wondering if you made progress here? Happy to share any info so we can debug it together if needed. I have at least 4 occurrences of this in NewRelic.

Comment: Sadly not, though I don’t recall seeing it for a while. Wonder if we have any dependencies in common?  We have Rails 5.1, and possible culprits that spring to mind include mysql2, hiredis, dalli, rmagick, and thinkingsphinx.

Comment: @Jonathan del Strother did you ever figure this out? getting this issue.

ah rack timeout can result in memory leaks it seems

Comment: We ended up removing rack-timeout and haven't seen it since. (I'm not blaming rack-timeout for bad behaviour here, it's really only intended as a bandaid)